# Can't SSH into an ODROID C2 with Debian Armbian image?

Tags: linux, ssh, debian

I just received an ODROID C2 IoT gadget. I flashed an Armbian image with Debian according to [Getting Started](http://docs.armbian.com/User-Guide_Getting-Started/). I am at the [How to login?](http://docs.armbian.com/User-Guide_Getting-Started/) step:

> Login as root on console or via SSH and use password 1234. You will be
>   prompted to change this password at first login. You will then be
>   asked to create a normal user account that is sudo enabled (beware of
>   default QWERTY keyboard settings at this stage).

The machine responds to pings but it does not allow me SSH access:

```
$ ping 172.16.4.5 
PING 172.16.4.5 (172.16.4.5): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.16.4.5: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.402 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.4.5: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.392 ms
^C
...
ssh: connect to host 172.16.4.5 port 22: Connection refused
```

I believe the machine has booted. I know it has an IP address. The blue LED is flashing two short ON, one OFF.

I seem to be having the same problem as the person at [Connection refused (via SSH)](http://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=1861). But the other fellow updated his system and lost access; I'm on a fresh install.

Does anyone know what's going on with the device? Does Armbian put their SSH access on a different port? Maybe something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does anyone know what's going on with the device? Does Armbian put their SSH access on a different port? Maybe something else?

The issue seems to be the instructions are wrong.

After flashing and upon first boot via the microSD card, the machine performs a *partial* command line boot. Its only partial because it stops and ask for a new *root* user password, complete with the old/new password prompt. After the password is changed the machine operates as expected, including adding a regular user and then booting into a desktop manager.

I did not realize the machine was waiting for input because there was no display, keyboard or mouse attached. In addition, the instructions said I could SSH into it without discussing other tasks, like attaching a monitor and keyboard to change the password prior to SSH access.

Comment: The server image boots up first and then you can switch the root pw / create your user. maybe it's better for your use.

Answer (score 1):

While installing Debian you get asked to choose additional Software to install. If you didn't select SSH-Server in the list you have to install it afterwards. I think you only can do that by connecting a Keyboard and Monitor to your ODROID and reinstalling it. You can follow this [Tutorial](https://wiki.debian.org/SSH#Installation) for installing Open-SSH Server

(Yes, I know its for Ubuntu but it shouldn't make a difference)

Otherwise you can try to reinstall Debian and selecting SSH-Server while installation.

Comment: if he uses armbian it's not his choice whether ssh is installed. infact it is, and likely they have a bug...

Answer (score 1):

Friend, save yourself some grief and flash the official odroid Ubuntu version.  You are probably long past this, but I installed Armbian and found that it was slower and lacked many of the Odroid/Hardkernel features.  The Odroid wiki recommends 'Etcher' which is the best 'flasher/formatter' that I've ever seen.  Etcher beautifully formats your card in one clean sweep.  Then you get an OS (Ubuntu or Android) that comes closer to working.